# Eliminate brackets in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with a list of items in a single column and without header:

[image]

I'm trying to attach the list to the body of an email and I would like an output like this:

```
[email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com, email3@domain.com, email4@domain.com, email5@domain.com]
```

However, with my code, I get an output like this:

```
['email1@domain.com'],['email2@domain.com'],['email3@domain.com'],['email4@domain.com'],['email5@domain.com']
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv

mail_list = csv.reader(open('/maillist.csv', "r"), delimiter = ' ')
emails = list(mail_list)
all_output =','.join(str(x) for x in emails)
print(all_output)
```

in the body of the email I have this code:

```
html= """\
     <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
             <p>User list""" + str(all_output) + """
             </p>
         </body>
    </html>
    """
```

The caveat is that **I cannot use pandas**. I haven't found much information about what to do where there is a pair of brackets per each item within the list. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use `csv`? Also, beware that this would leave the file opened until the script finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the first column of each row in a generator expression and join the values with `', '.join`:

```
with open('/maillist.csv') as file:
    all_output = ', '.join(email for (email,) in csv.reader(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this "by hand", e.g.:

```
with open('emails.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    emails = [line[:-1] if line[-1] == '\n' else line for line in file_obj]

all_output = ', '.join(emails)
print(all_output)
```

or, more elegantly, with `.rstrip()`:

```
with open('emails.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    emails = [line.rstrip() for line in file_obj]

all_output = ', '.join(emails)
print(all_output)
```

(EDITED: to include @Daniel's comment)

Comment: You could use `line.rstrip()`.